# Raspberry Pi 3 Shutdown sequence

Tags: pi-2, pi-3

is there any sequence for shutting down a running Raspberry Pi 3?
What I read from the datasheet is there's a start up sequence, start with 5V, then 3.3V then 1.8V. How about is shutting down? Can I shutdown the Power instantaneous?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any other way?  The Pi3 is powered from the 5V rail.  The 5V rail supplies the 3V3 and 1V8 power.  Perhaps you are being confused by the compute module which does have special power sequencing requirements.

Answer (score 1):

IC Startup/shutdown sequences are of interest to board designers, not to end users. As a user, you simply power up your board when you need it, and pull the plug when you're done (that is, when your OS has shut down properly), and the correct power-up/power-down sequence is staged automatically by the components present on the board.

The reason why start-up sequence is described in the datasheet is because it's typically more important than shut-down sequence. For example, you want to power up your clock generator before you attempt to start the CPU, as it will lock up if not clocked properly. During a shut-down, you don't really care what goes down first: in the worst case the clock will disappear while the CPU is still powered, so it will sit locked up for a few milliseconds before all power is lost. Typically there's no harm in that.